# Permanently associating a website's account to facebook account

Tags: facebook, web, external, credentials

I have the task to integrate some commercial sharing stuff into a website.
The idea is that the user a) logs in/registers in the website, b) the user connects his user account with his facebook account - by adding and accepting the website application.
Here comes the interesting part - is there a way of linking the facebook account with my website's account so that I can send them updates and promotions directly to their walls programatically?

In the application dialog, it's clearly noted that the user allows the application to write to the user wall so they accept and agree this. Then, for example, if I want to send them a promotion or update directly on their wall using the fb application api, how can I achieve this? All the tutorials I've read consider the user using the Facebook Login

The concrete idea is something like weekly promotion feed that my clients want to allow customers to allow being posted directly on their walls. As I don't have any experience with facebook development, I'd appreciate knowing how, if at all possible, this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of what you're suggesting is against policy, and isnt' technically possible either as users need to come back to the app once every 60 days for you to have a valid access_token for them.

The [Authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) docs explain how to get access to a user's information with their permission, and the [Permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) documentation explains which permissions grant access to which functions or fields.

Comment: Better solution IMHO: Get your page into the Open Graph and have them like it – then you can “push” updates to them as any other fan page on Facebook could. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/